# Cómo agrupar una columna de fechas por intervalos de tiempo en python sin usar Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos, python3.6

El problema es que el servidor en el que estamos trabajando, no podemos usar ni descargar pandas (cuestiones de seguridad de la empresa...).

tenemos un archivo training.csv que contiene por ejemplo:

```
 DATE,VALUE1,VALUE2
04/04/2021 00:00, 136,22
04/04/2021 01:00, 111,23
04/04/2021 03:00, 124,24
04/05/2021 00:00, 125,22
04/05/2021 01:00, 131,21
04/05/2021 03:00, 132,11
04/06/2021 00:00, 145,12
04/06/2021 01:00, 12,15
04/06/2021 03:00, 36,16
```

me gustaría poder agrupar por fechas pero hora en común, y tomando las columnas date y value1 por ejemplo:

```
#DATEs 04/04/2021 , 04/05/2021 y 04/06/2021 a las  01:00
 DATE,VALUE1
04/04/2021 01:00, 111
04/05/2021 01:00, 131
04/06/2021 01:00, 12

#DATEs 04/04/2021 , 04/05/2021 y 04/06/2021 a las 03:00
     DATE,VALUE1
     04/04/2021 03:00, 124
     04/05/2021 03:00, 132
     04/06/2021 03:00, 36
```

ya que estos datos serán procesados pero primero quiero lograr este filtro de forma dinámica ya que manejamos muchas fechas. Con pandas vi que se puede lograr de manera mas sencilla pero no lo podemos usar :( la versión de python es 3.6

Comment: Imagina que tienes una función que te hace el trabajo. ¿Qué recibiría esa función como parámetro? Por ejemplo: el nombre del fichero csv  y una hora. O bien: una lista de cadenas que son las líneas del fichero, y una hora, y un rango de fechas. ¿Qué devolvería? Por ejemplo: la lista de las filas que pasan el filtro. Definir así lo que haría esa función ayuda a clarificar el problema, para poder darte una solución. Por favor, edita la pregunta para añadir esta información.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más general es hacer una función que reciba el archivo y retorne la información agrupada por fechas. Para esto usare un diccionario indexado por hora y que contiene una lista de las lineas con esa hora. Cada línea se representa como un string "fecha, valor1".

El `for` procesa cada línea. El primer `split` la separa en "fecha hora" y "valor1" primero, y el segundo, en "dia" y "hora". La "hora" la usamos como llave del diccionario.

```
def filtrar(archivo):
    with open(archivo, "r") as datos:
        header = datos.readline()
        dicc = {}
        for linea in datos:
            fecha, valor, _ = linea.split(",")
            dia, hora = fecha.split()
            nuevo = f'{fecha}, {valor}'
            if hora not in dicc:
                dicc[hora] = [nuevo]
            else:
                dicc[hora].append(nuevo)
        return dicc
```

**Demo**

*training.csv*

```
04/04/2021 00:00, 136,22
04/04/2021 01:00, 111,23
04/04/2021 03:00, 124,24
04/05/2021 00:00, 125,22
04/05/2021 01:00, 131,21
04/05/2021 03:00, 132,11
04/06/2021 00:00, 145,12
04/06/2021 01:00, 12,15
04/06/2021 03:00, 36,16
```

*código*

```
from pprint import pprint
dias = filtrar("training.csv")
pprint(dias)
```

produce:

```
{'00:00': ['04/04/2021 00:00,  136',
           '04/05/2021 00:00,  125',
           '04/06/2021 00:00,  145'],
 '01:00': ['04/04/2021 01:00,  111',
           '04/05/2021 01:00,  131',
           '04/06/2021 01:00,  12'],
 '03:00': ['04/04/2021 03:00,  124',
           '04/05/2021 03:00,  132',
           '04/06/2021 03:00,  36']}
```